# All textures upside-down

Tags: texturing, uv, import

I imported a large scene of Wavefront .obj format and I discovered that every texture in the scene is upside-down. Is there a way to import the textures properly or flip everything on the Z axis? If I have to use Python, how do I change the size of every texture to flip it. Everything is UV mapped.

[image]

And i prefer not to flip the textures from the image files themselves.

Comment: Could it be that your faces are flipped? Try recalculating the normals.
to do this you can press 'N' while in edit mode.

Comment: Another solution to get the correct mapping is to select all while in edit mode and then press 'S' to scale and type in -1 on your numpad.
The reason why you should do it in edit mode and not object mode is that this way your object still has a scaling value of 1 instead of -1

Comment: Well I would have to combine all the objects and do that.

Comment: I don't think you need to do this. Could you post some screenshots to your question? This would be easier to comprehend the scene.

Answer (score 1):

In python it's not very hard : http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/flip-texture-v-coordinate.html

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def mission1(mesh):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)

    for uvt in mesh.uv_textures:
        uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv[uvt.name]

        for face in bm.faces:
            for loop in face.loops:
                loop[uv_layer].uv[1] = 1-loop[uv_layer].uv[1]
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    mesh.update()

if bpy.context.mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

meshes = set()
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.select:
        meshes.add(obj.data)

for mesh in meshes:
    mission1(mesh)
```

Just select all the defective meshes and it will flip the V coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to mirror all UV islands like this.
Join the models or use MultiEdit addon and enter Edit mode.
Select all and open UV editor. Switch pivot to Individual origins and mirror all by CTRL+M and X or Y.
Then separate models or exit from MultiEdit edit mode.
If it doesn't work for you, upload the model here and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm. Select the faces that are upside down (all, as you say in your case) and in the uv mapping editor, select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>R</kbd> and rotate it by 180 degrees. If something goes out of bounds, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Just one lil problem. They're different objects. And it would be quite difficult to combine everything and seperate correctly.